# QueryString Using in Asp.net

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

i am using query string method to pass the value form one page to another.
the code is `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?FirstName=" +Server.UrlPathEncode(TextBox1.Text) + "&LastName=" +TextBox2.Text.Replace(" ","%20") + "");` but the value is not hiding on address bar. i can value on the address bar on next page.

Comment: `the value is not hiding on address bar` - I don't understand that. Do you mean it is not showing?

Comment: i means this is showing the value in address bar.

Comment: and i want to hide the passing value in address bar.

Comment: Well, you are passing the values on the URL - you can't "hide" them. You need to change your design if you want to pass values between pages and not use the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear for me, but if you have problem with passing parameters between pages and with showing/hiding this parameters then you should read about GET and POST method. Here is similar problem to yours: [GET and POST in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242537/get-and-post-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to have a way to maintain values across pages, then you can use [Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).